# Loading component data in Joomla with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, joomla

I'm switching over my component to use AJAX to make for prettier/easier/faster/better pagination and content loads.

I'm trying to get past the first part which is simply displaying the content from a mySQL/PHP query.

Since I already had the query built, I figure why re-invent the wheel?  ...but it would help if I knew what a circle looked like, so to speak.

Here is the basic `AJAX/jQuery` function I'm trying to use:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({  
    cache: false  
});  

var loadUrl = "http://www.mgoode.com/index.php";  

$("#load_basic").click(function(){  
   $("#result").load(loadUrl, "option=com_mls&view=list&lprice=100000&pstart=5&plimit=5");  
});
```

I'm hoping that in the future, when I implement pagination, I can just alter the variables in the URL arguments and not have to re-do a bunch of stuff.

**I have a JSFiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6vt92/26/).**  I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** So, I just remembered that all of my element creations happen in the template itself.  So, no wonder the JSFiddle will only show up blank.  Sorry to bother you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Using Joomla with AJAX is a beat tricky but works fine if you structure your files right

Since you can't provide us with your PHP I'll pass you a recent modification I had made.
My goal was to use com_mycomponent within a module and retrieve some data from the db

My default.php for the module (modules/mod_mymodule/tmpl/default.php) looks like this

```
<form id="myform" name="myform">
<label>Push this to load some data</label>
<input type="text" id="myid" name="myid"/>
<a href="#" id="pushme">Push me</a>
<div id="component data"></div>
</form>?
```

It's a pretty form to grab an ID to make a simple SQL query

On my component I had to modify controller.php (component/com_mycomponent/controller.php)

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
class MyComponentController extends JControllerLegacy
{ 
public function myFunction()
    {
         $id = JRequest::getString('myid', '', 'method', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW);
         //grab the id
         $db->setQuery('SELECT username FROM #__mytable WHERE id='.$db->Quote($id));
         //fetch data
         $json['returned'] = $result->name;
     echo(json_encode($json));
        }
}
?>
```

The code above takes the posted ID makes a query and returns some data
Least but not last my jQuery function

```
$('a#pushme').click(function(){ 
$.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?option=com_users&format=raw&task=loginme',
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {

       if(data!=null)   {
});
```

Comment: What I'm hoping to do is **1)** keep the current MVC process intact, **2)** Create a PHP page within the template folder that displays the data from the query, **3)** Create an AJAX function that runs a URL with specific mySQL arguments and puts it into an element.  I don't know if this is a standard/good way to do it, but I'm hoping it works.

Comment: As I can see you are trying to retrieve content from a function of com_mls. How are you going to create a page within your template folder?

Comment: I'm hoping I can make a "content.php" file in the tmpl folder that places the items from the array into some readable html. ie `foreach($array as $key => $value){ echo "<div>" . $value['city'] . "</div>";}`.  This script is then run by the AJAX script, the AJAX script is run on user interactions.  So it'd go `USER->AJAX->"content.php"->AJAX->HTML->USER`, if that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I got it in first place but your logic is wrong. If you want to access values and files used by a specific component you have to convert the component itself. In your case is com_mls or else you have to call your component framework inside content.php

Comment: I realized that later.  Nothing in content.php ever ran the query.  I've read about using tasks in the controll (like you demonstrated) to accomplish this.  I'm going to look into that.

Comment: Actually you can render your component's attributes in an external php file but it's too sloppy, if you want extra help just hit me and I will edit my response